# Unittest failed when selecting Run All

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am using Shim Fakes and Moq Mock with VS 2015; when I run selected unit test methods, there is no error, but when I select "Run All" unit test cases, there are errors. What is the life cycle of ShimsContext, and how can it have impact on other test cases when selecting "Run All"?

Answer (score 0):

I found it used a singleton instance in a class which I did not use Fake for that class and caused another unit test failed, after changing to use Fake of that class, I am able to fix the error.
but my question is that the failed unit test case used Mock object of that singleton class, why is it still failed? 
the two unit test cases are in same unit test project but in different unit test classes.